Error on install testlink (Uncaught Error: Attempt to modify property)
I'm installing testlink on my machine, but I've been receiving successive errors like the one below:
Warning: Constant TL_CSS_MAIN already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\cfg\const.inc.php on line 180

Warning: Constant TL_CSS_PRINT already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\cfg\const.inc.php on line 181

Warning: Constant TL_CSS_DOCUMENTS already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\cfg\const.inc.php on line 182

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "prefix" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\config.inc.php:151 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\install\installNewDB.php(37): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\config.inc.php on line 151

Does anyone know what it could be and how to resolve it?
I tried to delete the variables with error from the config.inc.php file but there are many variables, when I delete one an error appears in others

Please post the code for us to help you out with the problem.
